# Array sort build in function

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, increment

I was wondering what's wrong with my program. Am i having a syntax error or am i missing something in my build in array sort?. I'm pretty sure the problem lies within the "for" loop but i cant seem to find it. Some suggestion or help would be great.

```js
<HTML>
<!Foundation Page for building our Javascript programs>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>The Foundation Page </TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">
function leaderboard()
{
var temp1;
var temp2;
var temp3;
var temp4;
var temp5;

temp1 = 10
temp2 = 20
temp3 = 30
temp4 = 40
temp5 = 50

var leader = new Array(5);

 leader[0] = temp1;
 leader[1] = temp2;
 leader[2] = temp3;
 leader[3] = temp4;
 leader[4] = temp5; 
 
 leader.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
 var myContent = '';
 for (var d=0;d<5;d++)
 {
  myContent += "score:  " + leader[d] + "<BR>";
 }
 document.getElementById("leaderboard").innerHTML = myContent;
}

</SCRIPT>
<HEAD>
<BODY>
<BODY BGCOLOUR = "WHITE">
<H2>The Foundation Page </H2>
<HR>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript"> leaderboard() </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: There's no `<something id="leaderboard">` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write the o/p to an element with id `leaderboard` which is not present in the page. Which is giving an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` - it is not a syntax error.

So just create an element with the id `leaderboard` as shown below

```
<HTML>
<!Foundation Page for building our Javascript programs>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>The Foundation Page </TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JavaScript">
function leaderboard()
{
var temp1;
var temp2;
var temp3;
var temp4;
var temp5;

temp1 = 10
temp2 = 20
temp3 = 30
temp4 = 40
temp5 = 50

var leader = new Array(5);

    leader[0] = temp1;
    leader[1] = temp2;
    leader[2] = temp3;
    leader[3] = temp4;
    leader[4] = temp5; 

    leader.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
    var myContent = '';
    for (var d=0;d<5;d++)
    {
        myContent += "score:  " + leader[d] + "<BR>";
    }
    document.getElementById("leaderboard").innerHTML = myContent;
}

</SCRIPT>
<HEAD>
<BODY>
<BODY BGCOLOUR = "WHITE">
<H2>The Foundation Page </H2>
<HR>
<div id="leaderboard"></div>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "Javascript"> leaderboard() </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7muq03pk/)